# Print content of a JavaScript tabcontrol: Gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, printing

I've got a jQuery tabcontrol (4 tabs), which each of them control 1 gridview.
Now I got a button "print". It activates a JavaScript function, which should build a page, containing all gridviews. I got something, but it does not work:

```
function doPrintPage() {
        myWindow = window.open('', '', 'titlebar=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=600');
        myWindow.document.open();
        myWindow.document.writeln("<link href='/styles/Layout.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' ></link>");
        myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('tabcontainer').innerHTML);
        myWindow.document.close();
        myWindow.focus();
        myWindow.print();
        return true;
    }
```

I thought it may be the `getElementByID()` and then something like `tabcontainer` (which contains the tabs) or `tabcontent` (the content of each tab) or `GridView1` or something, but I could be completely wrong. As I  ain't got a clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
function doPrintPage()
{

myWindow = window.open('', '', 'titlebar=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600');

myWindow.document.open();
myWindow.document.write("</br>");
myWindow.document.write("<h2>Results</h2>");
myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('tab1').innerHTML);
myWindow.document.write("</br>");
myWindow.document.write("<h2>Tree</h2>");
myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('tab2').innerHTML);
myWindow.document.write("</br>");
myWindow.document.write("<h2>Open</h2>");
myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('tab3').innerHTML);
myWindow.document.write("</br>");
myWindow.document.write("<h2>Free</h2>");
myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('tab4').innerHTML);

myWindow.document.close();

myWindow.focus();

//myWindow.print();

//myWindow.close();

return true;

}
```

The separate gridviews were embedded in div's ("tab#"), which were embedded in the tabcontainer.

Simple solution...
select the correct div ID...
Apparently I overlooked this one.